# redirecting back to index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm building a web app that uses devise. Upon signup with :email, :password, and :password confirmation, the new user is redirected to a second form where they will enter social information (such as hobbies, age, location, etc...) right now the form only contains fields for first and last name.

After submitting the second form, the user should be redirected back to the users#index page which is also where users who are signing in are redirected to. I just created the second form, and after submitting I get the following error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/users/user/edit_profile"
```

Below are the relevant files. I'm pretty new, does anyone have any ideas about this?

routes.rb

```
Appname::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

  devise_scope :user do
    get 'register', to: 'devise/registrations#new'
    get 'login',    to: 'devise/sessions#new',     as: :login
    get 'logout',   to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
  end

  resources :users do
    member do
      get 'edit_profile'
    end
  end
  root to: "home#index"
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get' 
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/legal',   to: 'static_pages#legal',   via: 'get'

end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
    def index
      @users = User.all
    end

    def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @user.update!(user_params)
      redirect_to @user
    end

    def destroy
    end

    def edit_profile_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to @user
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :hobbies)
    end

end
```

edit_profile.html.erb

```
<h2>Tell us about yourself</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: edit_profile_user_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>

  <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %>

  <div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>
```

here are my rake routes:

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)         devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)     devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)    devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)           registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                  registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)          registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)             registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                  registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                  registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                  registrations#destroy
                register GET    /register(.:format)               devise/registrations#new
                   login GET    /login(.:format)                  devise/sessions#new
                  logout GET    /logout(.:format)                 devise/sessions#destroy
       edit_profile_user GET    /users/:id/edit_profile(.:format) users#edit_profile
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                  users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                  users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)              users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)         users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)              users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)              users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)              users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)              users#destroy
                    root GET    /                                 home#index
                   about GET    /about(.:format)                  static_pages#about
                 contact GET    /contact(.:format)                static_pages#contact
                    help GET    /help(.:format)                   static_pages#help
                   legal GET    /legal(.:format)                  static_pages#legal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `edit_profile_user_path(@user)` instead.

In the Devise login-page, the value of `resource_name` is just a string `"user"`... you want to be pointing at an actual user's page, for that you need an actual user instance.... which for Devise's login page is what is stored in `resource`... but after you're logged in, it's stored in `current_user`.

However, your code seems to indicate that you're putting user into `@user` - so that's what I'd use.

Comment: Taryn, I get the following error when doing that: No route matches {:action=>"edit_profile", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Ok - so where did you get the idea for using the resource from? Did you copy that from a devise page? if so - you're probably using the logged-out user, and you probably just need to use `current_user` instead of `resource`.

Comment: Got the solution. So I had a edit_profile_user defined in my users_controller. Whereas I just needed edit_profile and take out redirect_to (at)user. Then I was just able to change the edit_profile.html.erb view to <%= form_for (at)user do |f| %> and add a route for post '/users', to: users#create.

This did it, but thank you so much anyway. To answer your question I did get all of that from Devise.

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    post 'edit_profile'
  end
end
```